# CSS Transition on page load

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to replicate the effect of the that you see in the pictures here: http://www.akqa.com/work/

I thought this was the code necessary for it but it doesn't work. What is missing?

```
div {
    opacity .4s,transform .4s
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

There are three things wrong here.

Firstly `opacity .4s,transform .4s` is not a valid CSS declaration.

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
div {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease .4s;
    transition: opacity .4s ease .4s;
}
```

Secondly, a `transition` rule implies that there are different values for the first and second instance (a point A and point B if you will). In the example below, you will notice that I have specified `opacity:0;` unless the `div` has a class `.showing` in which case it now has a rule that states `opacity:1;`

```
div {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease .4s;
    transition: opacity .4s ease .4s;
}

div.showing {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Lastly, you will also require **something** to change the state of the `div` to "let it know it needs to change it's opacity". We already told it in the CSS above that when it has a class `.showing` it's opacity is different.

A nice way to do this is to add a tiny jQuery script to give it the new class once the page has fully loaded.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $('div').addClass('showing');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the example I mentioned it is a mix of opacity change and moving upward. How can I do the moving too?

Comment: add `transform: translateY(50px);` to the CSS for `div` and `transform: translateY(0);` on the CSS for `div.showing`. Then adjust the `transition` rules and replace the word `opacity` with `all` like this `all .4s ease .4s;`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you focus on the text popup effect after mouse over the image? If yes, i did some trace from the html and css file.

```
<article class="work-item in-view" ...>    
 <picture>
  <source></source>
  <source></source>
  <source></source>
  <img></img>
  <div class=content>
    /* pop up text content*/
  </div>
 </picture>
</article>

.work-item {
background-color: #000;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%
}

.work-item .content {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
bottom: 0;
color: #FFF;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 0 30px;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
-webkit-transition: background-color .4s;
transition: background-color .4s;
width: 100%
}
```

I hope this findings may help you.
If the direction is correct, you can grep 'work-item' and 'content' from the css and follow the logic.

Comment: Nope sorry I'm interested in the trasition of the images as you load the page not the hover effect